# Remote Debugging on the Atari ST

Tags: atari, atari-falcon, atari-st, debugging

Were there ever any remote debugging tools for the Atari ST line of machines? When developing games in full screen modes, switching away to a debugger seems quite cumbersome if you need to remember what was on screen.

Are there any remote debuggers that can either show the disassembled binary or actual C source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [Db](http://dev-docs.atariforge.org/files/Atari_Debugger_1-24-1990.pdf) is a debugger for the Atari ST and TT series of 68000-family
>   computers... Db can use any of the ST's character devices for its
>   input and output, including the screen, the serial port, and the MIDI
>   port... Db is capable of debugging programs running on one machine
>   while the bulk of the debugger runs on another.

It lets you view the state of the registers and the memory, and there's a way to load symbols, presumably to make the disassembled code easier to read? Maybe someone who has actually used it can describe the workflow.

Comment: Nice, I'll check that out! Impressive that it can use the MIDI port :)

Comment: @Matt In fact, they recommend using the MIDI port because it's faster than serial and frees up the serial port for other uses.

Comment: Wonder if I can get that going with a USB->MIDI adapter... will definitely have to play around with this, sounds very useful!